# How can I bug proof walls before they are sealed up?

Tags: drywall, pest-control

How can I make a wall bug proof or resistant?  I know about in wall pest control tubes but I am looking for other solutions.

I fixed a wall damaged by water. I replaced the wood and drywall and I added insulation. I want to know if adding boric acid or diatomaceous earth to the wall will help reduce the number of bugs coming in my house. If I do add either how long would they last?

Comment: For clarity, do you have an existing bug problem and you're looking to build in mitigation, or is this a general preemptive strike to prevent possible future problems? Is this an interior wall or exterior? Generally, though, you don't put either _in_ the wall you put them in the ground outside. Also, you would generally surround the whole house, not just one wall.

Comment: @FreeMan I have a room that has multiple walls that seem to be a constant bug problem. But I only have 1 wall exposed as it has a water leak that needed to be repaired. So I want to do what I can for this wall with the expectation I will do it to the other walls if I expose them.

Comment: Interior or exterior walls? What kind of bugs?

Comment: I saw the new construction and focused on that, what kind of bugs? I had a home where lady bugs swarmed every year , changed the exterior color. Sealing all the cracks did it but they still swarmed, a nursery comes and gets them at that house if they were other bugs I would probably kill them beetle’s and others. But sealing around the windows and house wrap under the siding would be my steps.

Comment: @EdBeal I am getting ants, spiders, and centipedes. I will focus on sealing outside walls and windows.

Comment: Ants are tough, sealing along the foundation where the siding meets and around the window to siding will probably be the best solution. Air sealing this room can be expensive but will stop everything. Some folks air seal common areas in duplex’s to keep smoke out.

Comment: what kind of spiders do you have .... i have several wolf spiders in the house that i leave alone ... they hunt down and kill any bug that gets into the house

Answer (score 1):

With modern construction I would ask for air sealing, if air cannot get out bugs can’t get in , some locations require it for energy conservation. As tight as modern houses are sealed up I would not want any products in the wall other than insulation.

Comment: This isn't "new construction" this is "newly reconstructed after water damage".

Comment: @FreeMan I updated the title to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting borax between the wall studs, this deters roaches in particular. I used about 4 lbs spread in all the stud spaces when the house and garage were built . I think it has worked well considering we are in the heart of roach country ( E.TX)) and very rarely see a roach in the house..